# Backbone tutorial: model.destroy + remove and unrender functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to understand this sample backbone codes from this [tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/5.html), but I can't get my head around why we need this is `dummy function` - any ideas what it is for?

```
  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, success, error){
    success();
  }
```

Then, `remove` and `unrender` functions seem to be the same - why do we need both of them?

And what is this line for,

```
this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
```

while we have bound the `remove` function and the click event to the dom?

also, we already have bound all functions (including `unrender`) in this line,

```
_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'swap', 'remove');
```

so why do we need this line below?

```
this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
```

You can read the entire code from that tutorial above, here is some of it,

```
// `Backbone.sync`: Overrides persistence storage with dummy function. This enables use of `Model.destroy()` without raising an error.
  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, success, error){
    success();
  }

  var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      part1: 'hello',
      part2: 'world'
    }
  });

  var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
  });

  var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li', // name of tag to be created
    // `ItemView`s now respond to two clickable actions for each `Item`: swap and delete.
    events: {
      'click span.swap':  'swap',
      'click span.delete': 'remove'
    },
    // `initialize()` now binds model change/removal to the corresponding handlers below.
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'swap', 'remove'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
      this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
    },
    // `render()` now includes two extra `span`s corresponding to the actions swap and delete.
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html('<span style="color:black;">'+this.model.get('part1')+' '+this.model.get('part2')+'</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="swap" style="font-family:sans-serif; color:blue; cursor:pointer;">[swap]</span> <span class="delete" style="cursor:pointer; color:red; font-family:sans-serif;">[delete]</span>');
      return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
    },
    // `unrender()`: Makes Model remove itself from the DOM.
    unrender: function(){
      $(this.el).remove();
    },
    // `swap()` will interchange an `Item`'s attributes. When the `.set()` model function is called, the event `change` will be triggered.
    swap: function(){
      var swapped = {
        part1: this.model.get('part2'),
        part2: this.model.get('part1')
      };
      this.model.set(swapped);
    },
    // `remove()`: We use the method `destroy()` to remove a model from its collection. Normally this would also delete the record from its persistent storage, but we have overridden that (see above).
    remove: function(){
      this.model.destroy();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `dummy function` exists in the tutorial so some Backbone functions can be used without an API to communicate to a server to add/update/remove data. When you call `Model.destroy()`, Backbone by default sends a DELETE request to your server. If you don't specify a url in your model, it will throw an error. By putting the dummy function in, it overrides the default action of trying to send a request to a URL, which doesn't exist in this tutorial; instead it will just simulate that the HTTP request was successful, even though it didn't actually make a call to the server.

`this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);` listens to when the model is removed, and calls the `unrender` function in the view, which removes the view that the model is (or was) associated with. Basically, the model, when removed, sends out a 'remove' event, which gets picked up by this binding.

`_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'swap', 'remove');` is there so if you use `this` in any of those functions (render, unrender, swap, remove). Depending on the function, `this` can lose context and refer to something other than the view. This ensures that `this` always refers to the view.

Comment: awww thanks for explaining the `dummy function`. Now I see what it is for! :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse Underscore's `bindall` and Backbone's `bind` as they serve entirely different purposes.

`_.bindall(this, ...)` sets the context for each of those events, so that when the handler is called, `this` (in this case the view) is passed as the context.

`this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender)` is binding an **event handler** so that `this.unrender` is called when the model is removed, triggering the `remove` event.

---

Normally `sync` would make a call to your data store; the dummy function just calls the success callback directly so that it appears the call was successful.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

The _.bindAll()-function is an Underscore.js-function that sets the scope for the function (i.e. defines what "this")

setting

`_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'swap', 'remove');`

makes sure that the functions 'render', 'unrender', 'swap' and 'remove' are executed with the ItemView instance as "this"

The line `this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);` on the other hand, binds the remove event on the model to the unrender-function.

The use of this.model.bind has been replaced by this.model.on, which also takes a third argument, the scope.

So, you can safely remove 'render' and 'unrender' from _.bindAll and do

```
  this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
  this.model.on('remove', this.unrender, this);
```

As far as I understand, you could have done:

```
remove: function(){
  $(this.el).remove();
  this.model.destroy();
}
```

and skipped the `this.model.on('remove', this.unrender, this);`, and thus the unrender function. But, with the approach used in the example, the view will remove itself from the DOM whenever destroy() is called at the model, so it's more versatile

Comment: Thank you very much for helping to understand and the suggestions :)